# how to check/uncheck only specific checkbox if there are multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, checkboxlist

```
<div style="height: 237px; margin-top: 5px; overflow-y: scroll;width:230px;" id="divContainer">
    <input type="checkbox" value="anxyzkur@xyz.com" class="ads_Checkbox" name="chk_[18510][email]" checked="" id="chk_">   
   <label style="position: relative;vertical-align:text-bottom;" for="chk_">item 25</label>
    <p style="padding-left:25px;margin-top:0;width:170px;" id="address">Ahmedabad</p>

    <input type="checkbox" value="abc@abc.com" class="ads_Checkbox" name="chk_[18549][email]" checked="" id="chk_">
     <label style="position: relative;vertical-align:text-bottom;" for="chk_">item3</label>
      <p style="padding-left:25px;margin-top:0;width:170px;" id="address">ahmedabad</p></div>
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/Urvisha123/ZCTNe/
>   please see this fiddle .

I have problem that when i click on second label checkboxes.then first checkbox is check/unchecking.

i dont want this .

Comment: Your Fiddle is Empty.

Comment: @RohitAwasthi please see my edited jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were same id for both checkboxes and label attribute "for"
Change these

```
<input type="checkbox" value="abc@abc.com" class="ads_Checkbox" name="chk_[18549][email]" checked="" id="chk_"><label style="position: relative;vertical-align:text-bottom;" for="chk_">item3</label>
```

To

```
<input type="checkbox" value="abc@abc.com" class="ads_Checkbox" name="chk_[18549][email]" checked="" id="chk__"><label style="position: relative;vertical-align:text-bottom;" for="chk__">item3</label>
```

If you are building these dynamically then it should be like this for example

```
<?php

for( $i=0; $i < 10 ; $i++)
{
?>
<input type="checkbox" value="abc@abc.com" class="ads_Checkbox" name="chk_[18549][email]" checked="" id="<?php echo 'chk_'.$i;?>">
<label style="position: relative;vertical-align:text-bottom;" for="<?php echo 'chk_'.$i;?>">item3</label>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: then what is the solution for this?

Comment: I pasted html but it get converted... wait I do fiddle

Comment: @User1988 See I have changed id="chk_" to id="chk__"  and same change  for="chk__" to for="chk__"

Comment: hello @rohitawasthi input id checkbox is made dyanamic so how to ?

Comment: @User1988 See updated post. you need to change "id" in loop. There must be only one element of one id in whole document.